# JSON body always empty in Node.js application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

I am building a simple application using Node.js. On the client, I am sending some JSON data using Ajax to the server with the following code:

```js
var data = {};
data.title = "title";
data.message = "message";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/myresult',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

The server side code handling this request is:

```js
app.post('/myresult', function (req, res) {
    var obj = {};
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

However the console log prints the response bode as empty, i.e. `body: {}`.

Why is the body value empty and how can it be filled with the title and message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express gets a kind help from [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).
Use it as a middleware to get the actual body content:

```
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

and then leave your code as it was:

```
app.post('/myresult', function(req, res) {
    var obj = {};
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

I expect this will work for you, but please note [`bodyParser.json()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions) as well, which might be better suited for your needs.

---

In addition, what's currently happening is since you have `processData: false`, it's basically sending this: `({"command":"on"}).toString()` which is `[object Object]` and there's your body parser failing. Try removing `processData` flag entirely.

Comment: Thanks, but I already had that included in my app.js file. Still returns body: {}.

Comment: @CmdrDoom
Check the answer, I updated the last part and added something which may be useful for you.

Comment: Still no luck. I can print out the request sent to the server but the body part is still empty.

Comment: Hey, app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true })); works!

Comment: Huh! Great. Sorry for hiding it. :)